# Javascript - Can't determine if JSON object contains true

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have a JSON object I'm retrieving from a server, sometimes its really simple such as:

```
{ "urls": ["http://google.com", "http://bing.com"] }
```

However I need to check if `urls['tasks']['ipv6']` contains true, the code I'm using is:

```
if (urls['tasks']['ipv6'] === true) {
  console.log('true');
}
```

But because urls['tasks'] doesn't exist I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ipv6' of undefined
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm having a really hard time find a solution online. I've also tried jQuery's $.isEmptyObject and would be happy with a jQuery based solution. For reference I'm actually using this code in node.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.

```
if (urls["tasks"] && urls["tasks"]["ipv6"] && urls["tasks"]["ipv6"] === true)
{
    ...
}
```

You can add `urls` checking at left as well if you need to and you can omit the middle check `urls["tasks"]["ipv6"]`, because if it's `undefined` it definitely isn't `true`.

The thing is that you have to check first whether upper level properties exist before drilling down. And since Javascript (as well as majority of today's languages) doesn't use **full boolean evolution** this works.

Comment: I think the middle `urls["tasks"]["ipv6"]` test is unnecessary. FWIW, what you refer to as *full boolean evolution* is also called *short circuit evaluation*.

Comment: @FelixKling: I edited my answer to include this info. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixKling: *Short circuit evaluation* is actually the opposite of the other term that was used as a compiler switch in Turbo Pascal years ago... :) But you're right it's about the same paradigm.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks :) I only knew the other term (and I was aware that it is actually the opposite). Anyways, it's clear :)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Thanks a heap it works great, I had no idea it'd evaluate like that.

Comment: "url.tasks && url.tasks.ipv6 === true" would be the short form

Answer (score 0):

```
if (urls && urls["tasks"] && urls["tasks"]["ipv6"] === true) {
    console.log("true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the typeof before you check for true or false...

```
if(typeof(urls['tasks']) != "undefined")
{
   if(typeof(urls['tasks']['ipv6']) != "undefined")  
   {
      if(urls['tasks']['ipv6'] === true)
      {
          console.log("I am true & I exist");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: *slightly* verbose but still invalid... `"undefined"` should be literals not strings... or use `typeof` operator that returns strings...